# Can the tutor test for plagiarism under these circumstances?

Tags: plagiarism, coursework, engineering

I have been trying to get into college, but there has been a lot to catch up on. I told the tutor that my friend, who is already doing the course, would be able to help me with my work if I was stuck.

> I am often at Anon's house or he is at mine, so we could always work together and I could catch up at home.

However, he replied with this:

> I also have grave concerns that you believe you could get information
>   from another current student, this is clearly an issue of plagiarism.
>   Anon's work will now be fully scrutinised due to your noted comments

I have trust in my friend and know he will not ever plagiarise.

I am in the UK, and I am not in the college (I am in a Level 3 apprenticeship for Software Development, he is doing Engineering). Is the tutor still allowed to scrutinise my friends work under these circumstances? And what is there I could do to prevent this?

I accept full responsibility for my actions, but I want to set things right and I just don't know if I can.

**Update:**
This has now been solved with thanks to Maarten Buis.

Comment: It's a sad world where two students studying together raises "grave concerns". I guess we should keep students in solitary confinement because god forbid that they could actually learn from one another.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I concur.  When I was a student, we were highly encouraged to work together in study groups, so long as we actually did the work ourselves.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a tutor decides that (s)he will look extra carefully at the work of a specific student because (s)he believes that that student might plagiarise, then there is nothing you can do to prevent it. However, as long as your friend does not plagiarise, there is no problem (other than the time wasted by the tutor).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will ask my friend to talk to his tutor about the issue. I appreciate your help

Comment: What would the outcome of such a meeting with the tutor be? If it were me, I would not make this any bigger than it is, and just not plagiarize. In that case there is nothing to talk about. The tutor will look carefully at any product by your friend, find that (s)he did not plagiarise and give grades based on the finding that no plagiarism happened.

Comment: Thank you again. However, if he produces some work which is remotely similar to another student in the class, what would the outcome of that be?
I don't want to make any of this any bigger but I caused the problem and feel like I need to fix it.

Comment: Remotely similar is not the same of plagiarism. You should have a bit of trust in the profesionalism of the tutor.

Comment: Put yourself in the position of the tutor. Imagine someone comes up to you and says: I know student X, and (s)he is not going to plagiarise. If I were that tutor, all kinds of alarm bells would go off... Sometimes the best thing you can do to difuse such situations is just do nothing.

Comment: I very much appreciate your support and advice. I had told my friend earlier about what was going on. It is sorted out now luckily. Thank you, friend

Comment: @CowboyRazor consider that he may have said that just to scare you into not doing plagiarism. Kind of a police officer saying "I'm watching you".

Comment: re: "remotely similar", I should hope that two people given the exact same assignment would generally produce work that is similar.

Comment: @Maarten: You have a point. However, this tutor apparently took an innocent comment about the asker studying with another student, and jumped straight to accusations of plagiarism. Unfortunately, I think this is cause to mistrust his professionalism.

Comment: @Maarten, your strategy - do nothing - is likely the correct one for now, but if this is all there is to the story I'd be cross with the tutor if I was the course convener. Students should be encouraged to work together and if the tutor could have issued a gentle reminder about not letting sharing of study time to accidentally morph into sharing of writing etc.

Comment: My advice would be to do nothing *now* but if the tutor hints at presumed guilt targeted solely at you and your friend (as in they are not just generally aggressive on this stuff) then I would ask for a meeting with the course convener, bring print outs of the email exchanges, explain how you collaborate with your friend and ask for guidance on how to collaborate without it being interpreted as cheating. So no whinging or telling tales: just ask for advice.